# Android isometric chessboard

Tags: java, android

With this code I draw a isometric chessboard out of single board-pieces `bmpWhite` and `bmpBlack`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (white == true) {
            color[i][j] = 0;
            white = false;
            }
            else {
                color[i][j] = 1;
                white = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    if (gameViewWidth == 0)
    {
        gameViewWidth = theGameView.getWidth();
        gameViewHeight = theGameView.getHeight();
    }
    for (int xx=0; xx < 7; xx++)
    {
        for (int yy=0; yy < 7; yy++)
        {
            int x_start=(yy * 23);
            int y_start=(gameViewHeight / 2) + (yy * 12);
            int xx1=x_start + (xx * 23);
            int yy1=y_start - (xx * 12);
            if (color[xx][yy] == 0)
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmpWhite, xx1, yy1, null);
            }
            else if (color [xx][yy] == 1)
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmpBlack, xx1, yy1, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

The output should a chessboar(8x8) with alternating colors. But the output is this:

[image]

As you can see the last two lines of the bottom and top are the same color.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

you have written :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        if (white == true) {
            color[i][j] = 0;
            white = false;
        }
        else {
            color[i][j] = 1;
            white = true;
        }
    }
}
```

but it seams you have an 8*8 board. so you must write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        if (white) {
        color[i][j] = 0;
        white = false;
        }
        else {
            color[i][j] = 1;
            white = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and also for the second part of the code

Comment: Okay now i know whats the problem: when the app draws the last line it draws it as 2 lines. But why?

Comment: I think in each loop you color the what ever is left from the board. I didn't understand you code completely.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loops are only looping 6 times. You're right to start on 0, but making it `int i = 0; i < 7; i++` it loops 1 short. Try making it `int i = 0; i <= 7; i++` or `int i = 0; i < 8; i++` both work.